# thereby + ing usage

Tags: grammar, word-usage, meaning

Diets that are high in saturated fat clog up our arteries, **thereby reducing the blood flow to our hearts and brains.**

Regular exercise strengthens the heart, **thereby reducing the risk of heart attack.**

Hello. I often come across such sentences in academic books. How should I think when translating such sentences? More importantly, how else could we write such sentences?

For example : The bomb exploded, destroying the building.
**The bomb exploded** and **it** destroyed the building. ? (cause - result ) or
Regular exercise strengthens the heart, **thereby  *which cause to reduce* the risk of heart attack.** or She forgot to tie her shoes, thereby tripping and falling down the stairs. She forgot to tie her shoes, **thereby she tripped and falled down the stairs.**She forgot to tie her shoes, **thereby **which cause to trip** and fall down the stairs

Finally, do you have a resource or book recommendation that specifically explains this subject?
Maybe there have been people who asked questions about this subject before, but believe me, I couldn't find the answer I wanted. Thank you...

Comment: "thereby which cause to" doesn't make sense in English.  Don't use that.

Comment: _Thereby_ means _because of this, as a result_, so there is no need to add 'which cause to' (which is ungrammatical anyway). _She forgot to tie her shoes, which caused her to trip and fall downstairs_.

Answer (score 2):

> Diets that are high in saturated fat clog up our arteries, **thereby**
> reducing the blood flow to our hearts and brains.

Let us replace **"thereby"** with **"and because of this,"** **"pronoun"** (pronoun for the main subject)

> Diets that are high in saturated fat clog up our arteries, **and
> because of this,** **they** reduce the blood flow to our hearts and
> brains.

Also note the change in the verb "reduce" in the second sentence and the first sentence.

Comment: First of all thanks for your reply.  diets = they  
Do we always think that there is a common subject in such sentences? Can you give other examples? Or can you suggest a resource that includes these examples?

Comment: I am glad that you found my answer helpful. Unfortunately I am unable to suggest you any resources. The reason is, I was in touch with academics and literature long back. Now I am not in touch with academics and literature. Oxford and BBC used to publish writing guides. I don't know if they still do.

Answer (score 1):

In your examples **thereby reducing** is more or less equivalent to **and this/these reduces/reduce**.

For example, you could reword the sentences as follows:

> Diets that are high in saturated fat clog up our arteries, and these [diets]
> reduce the blood flow to our hearts and brains.
>
> Regular exercise strengthens the heart, and this [exercise] reduces the risk of heart
> attack.

You can't say **thereby which cause to**. This doesn't make sense in English, although it may make sense in your language.  Good luck with your translation!